Multi-colored linear box shadow flutter

I'm trying to create a button in Flutter that has a multi-colored box shadow effect similar to the one in the image below:
I've attempted to use the BoxShadow property in a BoxDecoration, but the shadows overlap each other, creating a less desirable effect. Here is my current code:
    class ColorfulShadowButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final String text;
  final double? width;
  final IconData? icon;

  const ColorfulShadowButton(
      {super.key,
      required this.onPressed,
      required this.text,
      this.width,
      this.icon});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      // width: width ?? double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        color: Colors.black,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.blue,
            blurRadius: 8,
            offset: Offset(3, 3),
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.red,
            blurRadius: 8,
            offset: Offset(3, 3),
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.orange,
            blurRadius: 8,
            offset: Offset(3, -3),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          if (icon != null) ...[
            Icon(icon, color: whiteColor, size: 15.0),
            widthBox5
          ],
          Text(
            text,
            style: const TextStyle(color: whiteColor, fontSize: 16.0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

However, the shadows seem to blend into each other rather than displaying distinctly. How can I achieve a more defined, multi-colored shadow effect similar to the image?
Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!
